# Android Studio cant run application after a long time

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

After about half a year of not working on the project, I had to open it up to do some minor changes. However upon opening the project without any issues, I get the following log message when trying to run it on my emulator:

```
GPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/BuildConfig) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/BuildConfig.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/BuildConfig.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$anim) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$anim.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$anim.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$attr) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$attr.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$attr.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$bool) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$bool.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$bool.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$color) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$color.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$color.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$dimen) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$dimen.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$dimen.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$drawable) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$drawable.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$drawable.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$id) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$id.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$id.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$integer) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$integer.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$integer.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$layout) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$layout.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$layout.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$mipmap) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$mipmap.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$mipmap.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$string) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$string.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$string.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$style) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$style.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$style.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"PARSE ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"class name (yifu/theindiestation/com/yifu/R$styleable) does not match path (Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$styleable.class)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"...while parsing Yifu/theindiestation/com/Yifu/R$styleable.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"15 errors; aborting","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.863 secs
```

I completely understand what "does not match path" means, but the thing is that I never changed the folders or whatsoever. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project several times, updated Genymotion, but still to no avail. Where can I start looking next?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to reset cache? updating genymotion is irrelevant

Comment: I have now. Had to do a search on how to do it, and I ended up moving the AndroidStudio folder out of the cache folder and see what it did. Unfortunately still the error. Or am I doing some with that? (I placed it back afterwards btw)

Comment: I mean the option `File -> Invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: Ah I see. Tried that now as well, but still get the same errors.

Comment: any more ideas?

Comment: you see that `Yifu` and `yifu` in the parts of the error have different casing, can you make sure that filenames folder names and names in manifest have same casing

Comment: I found some inconsistencies in Manifest and build.gradle, but when I changed them, I got even more errors.